# I've bought a domain name from namecheap and I host my website from my own PC, how to associate domain name to ip?

Tags: web

I'm trying to map my ip to the domain name I bought but little did I know, it's more confusing than I thought it would be. Where exactly does the link between the IP and the domain name happens? Does it have something to do with nameservers or domain redirections?

Comment: Who did you buy the domain from? They domain provider will usually have a feature that will allow you to change the host. You need to map it to your outbound IP address. Here's Godaddy's KB article: https://www.godaddy.com/help/change-my-ip-address-20134

Comment: It happens in a Domain Name Server (DNS)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: I bought the domain from namecheap.

Comment: @Andreas you can just flag it and the mods will take care of it if that's the case.

Comment: Why don't you **ask namecheap**? https://www.namecheap.com/support/live-chat/domains.aspx --- Better yet, **read their instructions**: [How do I set up host records for a domain?](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx?type=article&contentid=434&categoryid=&articletitle=how-do-i-set-up-host-records-for-a-domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to update your DNS settings and point to the IP you want.
The company / website your domain is registered with will be able to help here / allow you to do this online.

be aware that a lot of residential addresses will have dynamic IP addresses which may change frequently causing you to need to update the DNS a lot. 
Id recommend looking at a free web host (freehostia.com for example) if you are able to host your website / server online